# What does Herokus metric graph display?

Tags: django, heroku, dyno

I use Heroku, but I'm either too dumb or am looking in all the wrong places to get info on how the dynos work.

I initially thought that a single dyno could run a bunch of different processes simultaneously. But I realized that if that were the case, then when I increased the dyno count, my memory usage would have gone down.

Since that isn't the case, it must mean that the memory usage graph actually displays the most memory-intensive dyno. But that doesn't feel right because that doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere.

So my question is are any of my assumptions correct and/or is there a helpful resource for having a better understanding of dynos?

Comment: this whole area and the lack of documentation has always been confused me. Def book marking this one.